# How do I center this nav menu?

Tags: html, css

```
<nav>
<a href="/C:\Users\Emily O\Documents\HTML\Osmer Javajam/index.html">Home</a> |
<a href="/C:\Users\Emily O\Documents\HTML\Osmer Javajam/menu.html">Menu</a> |
<a href="/C:\Users\Emily O\Documents\HTML\Osmer Javajam/music.html">Music</a> |
<a href="/C:\Users\Emily O\Documents\HTML\Osmer Javajam/jobs.html">Jobs</a> |
<a href="/C:\Users\Emily O\Documents\HTML\Osmer Javajam/about.html">About</a>
</nav>
```

I need to know for my homework and I have no idea what it do cause I'm terrible at my class. I have a css sheet too idk ive been working on this for hours i hope it makes sense.

Comment: Please show some CSS of what you tried and explain what means ***center*** in your exact context. Also... a quick Google at `how to center elements` or `how to center anything in CSS` would make you less terrible at your class ;)

Comment: Hi Daisy, are you using any CSS along with the code you gave? Ideally, we need to see that as your code doesn't relate to actual styling and positioning.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `text-align`

```css
nav{
   text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<nav>
<a href="/C:\Users\Emily O\Documents\HTML\Osmer Javajam/index.html">Home</a> |
<a href="/C:\Users\Emily O\Documents\HTML\Osmer Javajam/menu.html">Menu</a> |
<a href="/C:\Users\Emily O\Documents\HTML\Osmer Javajam/music.html">Music</a> |
<a href="/C:\Users\Emily O\Documents\HTML\Osmer Javajam/jobs.html">Jobs</a> |
<a href="/C:\Users\Emily O\Documents\HTML\Osmer Javajam/about.html">About</a>
</nav>
```

the above will not actually center the `nav` element but it's inline text content.

Comment: That's not really the best approach if you want to change the width height and color of pipe but it can go